# Styling breadcrumbs using CSS

Tags: css

So here's the code I'm using to style my breadcrumbs.

```
.breadcrumbs-one{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:-20px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one li{
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a{
  padding: .7em 1em .7em 2em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f5f5f5, #ddd);  
}

.breadcrumbs-one li:first-child a{
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a:hover{
  background: #fff;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a::after,
.breadcrumbs-one a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;   
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid;
  right: -1em;
}

.breadcrumbs-one a::after{ 
  z-index: 2;
  border-left-color: #ddd;  
}

.breadcrumbs-one a::before{
  border-left-color: #ccc;  
  z-index: 1; 
}

.breadcrumbs-one a:hover::after{
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.breadcrumbs-one .current,
.breadcrumbs-one .current:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
}

.breadcrumbs-one .current::after,
.breadcrumbs-one .current::before{
  content: normal;  
}
```

I got it from here: http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-breadcrumbs

How do I modify the code so the CSS triangle isn't appended to the last breadcrumb?

So if there is one breadcrumb I wouldn't append a triangle at the end of it.

Similarly, if there are two breadcrumbs, I don't want a triangle at the end of the second breadcrumb.

And so on and so forth.

Comment: the left edge of the breadcrumb becomes completely rectangular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the last li element with the [last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) selector. After that you delete the content of the [pseudo classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) after and before.

```
#breadcrumbs-one li:last-child a::before,
#breadcrumbs-one li:last-child a::after
{
  content: normal;
}
```

In this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbudt/)** you have selected the second link and you can see that the last link has no arrow after it.

If you want select a specific index element, for example the third li element. You can use the selector [nth-child(index nummer)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp). So for example, if you want to select the third li element you could do li:nth-child(3).

In this case :

```
#breadcrumbs-one li:nth-child(3) a::after,
#breadcrumbs-one li:nth-child(3) a::before
{
 content: normal;  
}
```

**[Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbudt/2/)**

---

**Update**

Now when you use the last-child selector and you have one element, that element will be seen as the last element. But you actually want that element not the have the idicator of last. So you have to use an other idicator for this. First, one element is the first and the last. You've already defined last-child so you could easially define the first-child element.

```
#breadcrumbs-one li:first-child a::after,
#breadcrumbs-one li:first-child a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
}
```

You want this code to have more priority then the last-child. Now you could use the [!improtant](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/) tag of css, however i strongly recommend you to not use this tag at all costs. One way to give more priority to a code is to make the selector more specific. In this case the #breadcrumbs-one is actually a ul element, so placing a ul before it makes it more specific:

```
ul#breadcrumbs-one li:first-child a::after,
ul#breadcrumbs-one li:first-child a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
}
```

Now if you don't want to make a more specific selector, you can always place this code after the last-child selector code. Css will read from top to bottom order, so you want the overlapping code to be readed after the code to be overlapped. *This order is only used when the selectors are identical.*

 However i choose the method of a more specific path, this way it doesn't matter where you place your code. 

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbudt/3/)**

---

**Lets add another update**

First of all i would suggest you to understand what happens. **[Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)** is a little example of how the arrows are created. With this the ::before and ::after pseudo classes are also used, **[Here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)** some more info about that.

I would suggest you to first try it yourself before reading my answer.

Each 'crumb' is defined by the bar with text, arrow next to it and the border of the arrow.

*So what psuedo class is generating what?*

Well simply, the ::after pseudo class is generating the arrow it selfs and the ::before pseudo class generates the border of the arrow. 
Now you only want the arrow color to be changed(you can change the border youself). Now if you have read the border-trick you may notice that this is created with only borders. This way you *don't* want to use `background-color` but change the border color.

You can change the border color with: `border: 1px solid white;`, however you only want to change the color. The way you do it now is also giving the width and border-style. With `border-color` you can change only the color. To be even more specific: `border-left-color: white;`.

So would have this:

```
#breadcrumbs-one .current::after
{
    border-left-color: white;
}
```

Remeber what i said earlier? A more specific selector will overwrite other css code. In this case a class is more specific as a element(anchor).

Now you have only changed the arrow color. Let's change the background of the bar itself.

There is already a css code that defines the .current element :

```
#breadcrumbs-one .current,
#breadcrumbs-one .current:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Just change the background of the element, so:

```
#breadcrumbs-one .current,
#breadcrumbs-one .current:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
}
```

There you go, the .current element is white by default!

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbudt/4/)**

Comment: yes that's what i wanted :) how can I do the same for the third crumb?

Comment: could you help me out with a slight modification? If there is only one crumb then I'd like the CSS triangle to appear at the end. However if there are two or three crumbs (as long as its more than one) then I don't want the CSS triangle to appear at the end of the last crumb.

Comment: You should take a look at the [::first-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild) selector for this. Check my update for more information :)

Comment: How can I further change this so that the current breadcrumb is always white? Basically I want the current breadcrumb to appear white just like it appears when hovering over a breadcrumb.

Comment: i mean I want the nth breadcrumb to always appear completely white. I'm using a black background on my page.

Comment: I hope you're still learning from this ^^ Look at my update, hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Yes I am, I appreciate your explanations. I would like to do this purely in CSS as I am not making use of the class current and I would like to avoid doing this.  That's what  I wanted help with. Let me create a fiddle and show you.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paulie/YS9JQ/ I want the nth child to be completely white. I tried putting that into the selector for the nth child but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh i see. Did you use selector `.breadcrumbs-one li:nth-child(3) a`?
Remeber that you have used a background-image. So you should set it to none so it doesn't overlay the background. Also remember to make your arrow also white when it has a arrow ^^ I hope, with info i already gave you, you can understand what i did **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YS9JQ/1/)**

Comment: What I meant was that if I have one crumb then I want the crumb to be white. If I have two crumbs, I want the second crumb to be white and if I have three then I want the third crumb to be white. I want to implement this to show the latest crumb without setting the class as current. I've added the suggestion you made over here but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried that before asking you about it again today but it didn't work. Well here it is, have a look:  http://jsfiddle.net/paulie/YS9JQ/3/

Comment: So you want the last crumb to be white? Just look at the first answer i gave, ::last-child selector. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YS9JQ/4/)

Comment: Yes but how would I get the CSS triangle to be white only in the case where there is one only crumb?

Comment: Well you actually don't want to have a arrow there(your last-child selector should be stronger then the first-child selector). look at the path i used, it's more specific so stronger. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YS9JQ/6/), Hope this is want you meant ;p

Comment: I actually want to have an arrow there cause the convention of not having an arrow there doesn't suit the design of my page.

Comment: Woops. Well here is with the white arrow [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YS9JQ/7/)

Comment: Having a small problem as my page background is black. Will get back to you on it in a bit if I can solve it. That isn't a problem on jsFiddle as the background there is white so it blends in.

Comment: Let's discuss this in **[chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38724/discussion-between-nkmol-and-paulie)**, this becomes too long ^^

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed the point of the question, it isn't. Even on the page you cite, it shows the last item in the list has a different CSS class

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs-one">
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Vivamus nisi eros</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nulla sed lorem risus</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nam iaculis commodo</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="current">Current crumb</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, just make sure your `class="current"` is on the last item in your list.

If this is dynamic, then it can be done with server sided code or probably some JavaScript